# Moment of weight of leaning beam

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics

[image]

Having trouble with a FBD moment. The problem is:

> *How big can the force couple C (looks like a G in the pic) be in order for the disk to not spin? The disc has mass m and the beam also has mass m. All other variables are given.*
>
> *Let point A = bottom the disc and point B = where the beam touches the ground. Also let $\ell = R/\tan(\alpha)$ = distance from point A to point B.*

In the solution sheet, the professor stated that the counter-clockwise moment about point A due to the beam is $\frac{\ell}{2} m g$, implying that the center of mass of the beam is located halfway between A and B.

How can this be? If the beam was parallel to the ground, surely that would have been the case. But now it's tilted $\alpha$ degrees - should that not shift the center of gravity to the right?

For reference, this is his equation of moment equilibrium about A:

$$M_a = N_b \ell - m g \frac{\ell}{2} + C = 0.$$

Comment: Is the beam rigidly attached to the disk, or just pinned?

Comment: It is pinned...

Comment: Surely rotating the bar (clockwise) would shift the COG to the _left_.

Comment: That's reasonable to think IMO, but the solution sheet does not agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two rigid bodies in contact to the ground. Let us call $N_a$ and $N_b$ the contact force (normal to ground) and $F_a$, $F_b$ the frictional force at *A* and *B* (arbitrarily chosen to act in a positive *x* direction). We can call the pin forces $P_x$ and $P_y$ acting on the bar (an reacting on the disk).

The sum of moments about the disk center is

$$ r F_a + C = I \ddot{\theta} $$

and about the bar center

$$ \frac{\ell}{2} \cos\theta (N_b-P_y) - \frac{\ell}{2} \sin\theta (N_b+P_x) = 0 $$

couple with the motion in the *x* and *y* axes of the disk

$$ m \ddot{x} = m R \ddot{\theta} = F_a -P_x \\
m \ddot{y} = N_a -P_y - m g = 0 $$

and the bar

$$ m \ddot{x} = F_b + P_x \\ 0 = N_b+P_y - m g $$

For the condition of motionless with $\ddot{x}=\ddot{\theta}=0$ the above is 6 equations for 6 unknowns ($P_x, P_y, N_a, N_b, F_a, F_b$) which is solved by elimination.

Next find which is the smallest $C$ value that makes $|F_a| = \mu_s N_a$ and $|F_b| = \mu_s N_b$

If you get the correct result you will have $P_x<0$ and $F_a<0$ and $C \propto \mu_s R m g $